# Monitor loopback traffic (monitor MS TCP Loopback inteface traffic) with Microsoft Network Monitor 3.4 - possible?

Tags: windows, networking, tcp, loopback, interface

I've downloaded NM 3.4 from microsoft.com and it appears that the software doesn't capture traffic on MS TCP Loopback interface. When I ping 127.0.0.1 address, NM shows no packets flowing. I've tried both promiscuous / standard NIC mode with no luck. The only way I know so far to capture loopback traffic on Windows machines is to use RawCap.

I'm using Windows XP SP3.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is "impossible" with Windows because the Microsoft TCP/IP stack [does not have a loopback interface like BSD systems do](http://www.hsc.fr/ressources/articles/win_net_srv/missing_loopback.html). In fact, you can't see traffic that is sent from one Windows PC to *any* IP address that is bound to a local NIC, even if they're non loopback addresses.

Having said the above, you can use a tool that utilizes [raw sockets in Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to capture any and all traffic that is being moved around in the PC. An example of such a tool would be [RawCap](http://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap). You would then save the capture that RawCap takes and import it into Network Monitor to examine.

Here are some references that should get you going in the right direction:

1. [Ethereal's discussion on loopback interface traffic](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback)
2. StackOverflow question: [Windows packet sniffer that can capture loopback traffic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46376/173803)

Answer (score 1):

As of 2014 this is possible with [Microsoft Message Analyzer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44226) (which replaced Network Monitor).   Instructions for configuring loopback capture are in [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2014/08/15/rejoice-we-can-now-capture-loopback-traffic/).  Note that the download link in the blog post is broken, but the link above should work.

I was able to successfully capture loopback traffic using this tool on Windows 10.

Comment: There is no need to configure, even. Just click `Loopback and unencrypted IPSEC` on the start page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible with packet capture tools since the packets never hit the interface.  You have to use a proxy of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Resource Monitor appears capable of capturing local traffic.  Under Network -> Processes with Network Activity Send and Receive local traffic between local processes shows up fine.  I'm still wondering how this is possible.  I think it's probably tracking read and write calls (like truss/strace on Unix/Linux).